# Loading CSV to Redshift, Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x76 found at location 38

Tags: python, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I want to load my csv to AWS Redshift,
file content as:

```
39334;sms|587b083b98420f9a11c414a9;verified;2017-04-07T05:45:14.479Z;2017-05-02T13:05:32.588Z;00f8a90d-518a-40a0-b663-c4070baf2459;1494012833;2017-05-05T15:33:53.990136-0400;None;2017-04-06T22:33:06-0700;47.451199;47.451199;no;yes;no;no;no;no;no;no;yes;yes;yes;yes;1;2.0.3.1;Optional('AT&T');iPhone;10.2.1;[Decimal('11'), Decimal('12')];Phone mount;Washington;CA337B1C-EEC9-4B0E-8A3C-F5DA959D47AB;Sun Jan 15 2017 05:27:33 GMT+0000 (UTC)**
```

I wrote the above content to csv through **Python**:

```
with open(self.path + ".csv", "a") as myfile:
    file_writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    file_writer.writerow([x.strip() for x in line.split(';')])
```

And then I uploaded to Amazon S3. After that I am trying to load my CSV file from S3 to Redshift, I used copy command:

```
copy table_name 'my_s3_location'
CREDENTIALS 'my_credential'
delimiter ',' region 'my_region';
```

While executing the copy command, Redshift throws an error as:

> Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x76 found at location 38

and I can't see 38th location, I have 34 column only.

Comment: It is referring to the 38th character on the line. Can you show us that data as it appears in the CSV file? Also, you should use the **CSV** parameter in your COPY command (but it probably isn't causing this problem).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I already post my csv content

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
copy table_name 'my_s3_location'
from bucketlocation
CREDENTIALS xxxxxxxxx
delimiter ';'
removequotes
acceptinvchars;
```

Comment: it's dlimited by ; or ,?

Comment: can you copy here ddl of the table you are copy data in?

Comment: Its not delimiter by ;. while writing into csv file I split by using ;

Comment: ok so could you show the actual CSV you are importing? Anyway, this is something has worked for me many times I have generated csv through scripts. Open the file with HxD or similar editor, look for bom characters that could be there. 99% of the times it worked for me.

Comment: When you say "its not working", what do you mean? What happens, how long does it take, what message is displayed? It is very difficult for us to help you unless you provide more information.